# Laço infinito com um if dentro de um do em Java

Tags: java, if

Boa noite. Estou realizando um trabalho da faculdade sobre um caixa eletrônico e estou com uma pequena dúvida. Estou criando um `do` para fazer o menu de repetição do caixa eletrônico, mas antes do usuário entrar no caixa, ele irá setar um valor para as contas, pois a variável saldo esta setada para 0. Após isso, ele será liberado para o menu do caixa. Mas após setar o valor o valor ele fica repetindo a mensagem `"teste"`. Gostaria de uma ajuda.

Eis o código:

```
do{
           if(saldoCC<=0 && saldoCP<=0) {
               System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
               System.out.println("Saldo zerado em ambas as contas!");
               System.out.println("Para utilizar o caixa eletrônico sete o valor!");
               System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
               System.out.println("DIGITE O VALOR PARA REPOR O SALDO");
               System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
               System.out.print("Saldo da CONTA CORRENTE: R$");
               saldoCC = teclado.nextFloat();
               System.out.print("Saldo da CONTA POUPANÇA: R$");
               saldoCP = teclado.nextFloat();

               System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
               System.out.println("SALDO SETADO!");
               System.out.println("Conta Corrente: R$"+ saldoCC);
               System.out.println("Conta Poupança: R$"+ saldoCP);                  
           }else{
            System.out.println("teste");
           } 


        }while(op != 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe que ele vai repetir o laço enquanto `op` for diferente de 3. Dentro do laço, em lugar nenhum ele muda a variável `op`. Assim sendo, supondo que `op` seja 3, então após ao menos um dos valores `saldoCC` ou `saldoCP` ser definido com algo maior que zero, o laço resultante ficaria assim:

```
do {
    if (condição sempre falsa) {
        // não importa mais
    } else {
        System.out.println("teste");
    }
} while (condição sempre verdadeira);
```

O que é equivalente a isso:

```
do {
    System.out.println("teste");
} while (true);
```

Para corrigir isso, não sei exatamente o que você faria, pois depende de informações que vão além do que você postou na pergunta, em especial de como você espera obter ou alterar o valor de `op`. Mas algumas das possíveis soluções seriam:

- Colocar uma instrução `break;` em algum lugar.
- Colocar uma instrução `op = 3;` em algum lugar.
- Colocar uma instrução `return;` em algum lugar.
- Lançar alguma exceção em algum lugar.
- Retirar o laço `do`.

Comment: Boa tarde! obrigado pela ajuda, coloquei um break; após o System.out.println("teste"); e funcionou! esta repetindo como eu queria!